# Unable to run the ec2 command lines using cron ,

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am automating the ec2 start and shutdown, I have written a bash script, which works when I run it manually, but when I add the bash to run by crontab its not executing. I have assigned proper permissions to the script. Here is my script

```
#! /bin/bash
/usr/local/aws/bin/ec2-start-instances --region us-east-1  i-abc12345
```

Here is my crontab

```
35 13 * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/.script/testshutdown.sh
```

Please help me out !!!

Comment: You may be missing some environmental variables that the ec2 command line tools require in the session that cron uses. You may want to try defining them in your script before you run the ec2 commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What output do you get from */var/log/cron* with regard to any errors? Further, if you put your a she-bang of #!/bin/bash at the start of the script, you don't need to tell cron how to execute the script. Make sure it's executable (*chmod +x testshutdown.sh*).

Are you editing /etc/crontab, running crontab -e, or otherwise? There's more than just one crontab on a system and they are edited differently in terms of number of values needed in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

My answer here might be the help you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21397517/2083509
Snippet:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY="blah-blah-dingle-smith" # changeme
AWS_SECRET_KEY="yankee-doodle-shit-no-stank" # changeme
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java"
EC2_HOME="/opt/aws/apitools/ec2"
EC2_URL="https://us-west-2.ec2.amazonaws.com/" # changeme
PATH="$PATH:/opt/aws/bin"  # is dir contains a symlinks of tool binaries
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SECRET_KEY JAVA_HOME EC2_HOME EC2_URL PATH
```

Add the above directly into your `testshutdown.sh` script. Or give it its own script and load it before yours on the same crontab job. ex: `* * * * * /home/ubuntu/.script/aws-env.sh; /home/ubuntu/.script/testshutdown.sh` or what i suggest todo from the link (source a *.conf) Using full access admin keys for specific tasks is never advisable. ;)

Might be wise to set your SHELL in cron itself. Replace or Add `SHELL=/bin/bash` to your cron. Even if you have proper shebang, its still a good decision. You might drive yourself nuts trying to find out why commands you know work, don't.