# EC2_HOME is not set. Run AWS Commands from Cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, cron, ec2-api-tools

Basicly I'm not sure how to get my aws commands to run in crontab. I know I need to give crontab some environmental variables so that it can run the aws commands but, I don't quite know how to do that. Has anyone been able to do this before?

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin
* * * * * export EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
* * * * * export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
0 8 * * 1-5 ec2-start-instances instance_id
0 7 * * 1-5 ec2-start-instances instance_id
0 7 * * 1-5 ec2-start-instances instance_id
```

I am on an EC2 Amazon machine and I'm able to run the aws commands in the EC2-user shell. I'm just having trouble getting the commands to run from crontab.

The mail sent to the ec2 user says "/opt/aws/bin/ec2-start-instances: line 9: EC2_HOME: EC2_HOME is not set"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you... Needed to setup a few systems with automated cron git pull scripts, which would then execute crontab/anacron run-parts bash scripts which called upon ec2 java tools. Normally in an amz-linux-ami (their RH clone) the creating of env vars goes as follows:

(going to stick to relevant files)

Do shell login --> `source /etc/profile` which will loop through /etc/profile.d and `source *.{users shell extension}` in this case `aws-apitools-common.sh`

```
$cat aws-apitools-common.sh 
 export AWS_PATH=/opt/aws
 export PATH=$PATH:$AWS_PATH/bin
 #Prefer JDK if present (i pulled the condition to de-clutter this info)
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
```

Here is the relevant line:

```
for aws_product in $(find /opt/aws/apitools /opt/aws/amitools -maxdepth 1 -type l 2>/dev/null); do
[ -e $aws_product/environment.sh ] && source $aws_product/environment.sh; done
```

So the script `aws-apitools-common.sh` searches for apitools and amitools, then sources those tools `$aws_product/environment.sh`. ex: `source /opt/aws/apitools/ec2/environment.sh`

Now this is probably what you are looking for (**/opt/aws/apitools/ec2/environment.sh**):

```
$cat environment.sh
# Set EC2_HOME.  Called from /etc/profile.d/aws-product-common
[ -z "$EC2_HOME" ] && EC2_HOME="/opt/aws/apitools/ec2"
export EC2_HOME
```

In short the environmental vars you want set/export in your crontab script, and or your anacron run-parted scripts would be (personally i load in key.conf files which are generated from a git repo, and having a git pull fire off every hour, so keys and the env cat be updated just like the scripts themselves. Then the job script sources the conf file):

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY="blah-blah-dingle-smith"
AWS_SECRET_KEY="yankee-doodle-shit-no-stank"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java"
EC2_HOME="/opt/aws/apitools/ec2"
EC2_URL="https://us-west-2.ec2.amazonaws.com/"
PATH="$PATH:/opt/aws/bin"  # is dir contains a symlinks of tool binaries
```

Cheers!

Comment: oops be sure to export those vars: `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SECRET_KEY EC2_URL JAVA_HOME EC2_HOME EC2_URL PATH` if you go the source conf route, probably wise not to execute the export there.

Comment: Also change the shell in /etc/crontab `SHELL=/bin/bash` and or /etc/anacrontab `SHELL=/bin/bash` I don't trust shebangs, especially when cronie gets involved.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should upgrade to the new AWS CLI.

Then you can put your access keys and secret keys into ~/.aws/config, and you won't have a problem.  The new tools support multiple profiles, and don't rely on env variables.

Edit:  If your problem is simply setting the env for jobs run from cron, take a look at:

[Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)

Comment: I am on an EC2 Amazon machine and I'm able to run the aws commands in the EC2-user shell. I'm just having trouble getting the commands to run from crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer on the AWS Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=424592#jive-message-447927) that worked for me. Just copied it here to make it easier to reach:

> You can source `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars` to set the usual environment variables (`RDS_HOSTNAME` etc). The following cron entry works for us:
>
> `30 2 * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && php /var/www/bin/some_command.php`